# Adding object to localStorage array

Tags: javascript, json

I have class method named **set**, that method should add new object to localStorage array, but I have problem with adding argument to this function.

```
set(data) {
    let movieList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'));
    movieList.push({
        data
    });
    localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(movieList));
}
```

After calling method:

```
b.set('id: 24, title: qwerty');
```

I got:

> {**data:** "id: 24, title: qwerty"}

I want to add object with input from data, how can I remove "data" from object? (I want just {id: 24, title: qwerty}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to creating an object when you call `set()`...wrap it in `{}` and tweak the quotes to make an object and just push that object

```
b.set({id: 24, title: 'qwerty'});
```

In set()

```
movieList.push(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying it but by reverse :)

Comment: I added new method (I need 2 of those method) and one of them has stopped working.
    `code:
set(id, data) {
        let movieList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'));
        for (let i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) {
            if (movieList[i].id === id) {
                movieList[i] = data;
                return localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(movieList));
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Not sure what *"stopped working"* means. What errors are thrown?

Comment: No errors, just method b.set(data) is no longer adding new object to array

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox site that reproduces the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/avfu3yvb/1/

btw. I have also problem with get() method, its returning undefined and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have several Objects and it will grow by time.
we have an object like

```
{name : "a" , age: 12}
```

add the Object to an Array

```
cosnt persist = []

persist.push({name : "a" , age: 12})
```

or save some lines and write

```
let persist = [{name : "a" , age: 12}]
```

or use ES6 syntax line

```
const persist =[]

[...persist, {name : "a" , age: 12}]
```

now you want to save the changes, for that

```
localStorage["Persist"] = JSON.stringify(persist);
```

and walla now your storage should be like this

```
[{"name":"a","age":"12"}]
```

If you need this information again

```
persist = JSON.parse(localStorage["Persist"]);
```

the value of "**persist**" would be an array of object that you add just right now

```
[{name:"a",age:12}]
```